# Magento PHP Created a new column in table, attempting to use column to filter and perform conditional statements

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I created a new column in the "*sales_flat_order*" table called "*gc_sent*", default value of *0*.

From here, I'm trying to perform an if statement below in the code, saying if the Card's gc_sent is 0, then send an email to the customer with their giftcard in it. Then set the card_status to 1, and gc_sent to 1.

However, what I'm running into in my dev environment, I'm receiving email after email, 1 per minute, with my gift card information in it. That shouldn't be happening. That's what I'm trying to prevent. That's why I'm doing conditions including curDate (current date), and MailDeliveryDate. To ensure that everything jives.

So, what am I doing wrong? What do I need to change? I'm relatively new to Magento, only been doing it for a few months now, by the way.

**The most relevant section is:**

```
    $curDate = date('Y-m-d');
    $cards = Mage::getModel('giftcards/giftcards')->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('order_id', $order->getId())
        ->addFieldToFilter('gc_sent', 0);
    foreach($cards as $card) {
        if (($card->getGcSent() == 0) && ($curDate == $card->getMailDeliveryDate())) {
            if ((($card->getMailDeliveryDate() == null) || ($curDate == $card->getMailDeliveryDate())) && $card->getCardType() != 'offline') {
                $this->_send($post, 'giftcards/email/email_template', $mail, $storeId);
                $card->setCardStatus(1)->save();
                $order->setGcSent(1)->save();
            }
        }
    }
```

**But this is the complete code:**

```
<?php
class Sportys_Giftcardoverride_Model_Giftcards extends Webtex_Giftcards_Model_Giftcards
{
    protected function _sendEmailCard($storeId = 0)
    {
        if($order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($this->getOrderId())){
            $storeId = $order->getStoreId();
        } else {
            $storeId = 1;
        }

        $amount = number_format(Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->convertPrice($this->getCardAmount(), false, false),2);

        if(Mage::helper('giftcards')->isUseDefaultPicture() || !$this->getProductId()) {
            $picture = Mage::getDesign()->getSkinUrl('images/giftcard.png',array('_area'=>'frontend'));
        } else {
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProductId());
            if (!$product->getId() || $product->getImage() != 'no_selection') {
                $picture = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image');
            } else {
                $picture = Mage::getDesign()->getSkinUrl('images/giftcard.png',array('_area'=>'frontend'));
            }
        }

        //Change picture if one is found in picture array
        $cardDesigns = __DIR__ . '/../../../../../../sportysadmin/giftcarddesigns.php';
        if(file_exists($cardDesigns)){
            include $cardDesigns;
        }

        $post = array(
            'amount'        => $this->_addCurrencySymbol($amount,$this->getCardCurrency()),
            'code'          => $this->getCardCode(),
            'email-to'      => $this->getMailTo(),
            'email-from'    => $this->getMailFrom(),
            'recipient'     => $this->getMailToEmail(),
            'email-message' => nl2br($this->getMailMessage()),
            'store-phone'   => Mage::getStoreConfig('general/store_information/phone'),
            'picture'       => $picture,
        );

        $mail = trim($this->getMailToEmail()) ;

        if(empty($mail)) {
            $mail = $order->getCustomerEmail() ;
        }

        $curDate = date('Y-m-d');
        $cards = Mage::getModel('giftcards/giftcards')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('order_id', $order->getId())
            ->addFieldToFilter('gc_sent', 0);
        foreach($cards as $card) {
            if (($card->getGcSent() == 0) && ($curDate == $card->getMailDeliveryDate())) {
                if ((($card->getMailDeliveryDate() == null) || ($curDate == $card->getMailDeliveryDate())) && $card->getCardType() != 'offline') {
                    $this->_send($post, 'giftcards/email/email_template', $mail, $storeId);
                    $card->setCardStatus(1)->save();
                    $order->setGcSent(1)->save();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected function _send($post, $template, $email, $storeId)
    {
        if ($email) {
            $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
            $translate->setTranslateInline(false);
            $postObject = new Varien_Object();
            $postObject->setData($post);
            $postObject->setStoreId($storeId);
            $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
            $pdfGenerator = new Webtex_Giftcards_Model_Email_Pdf();
            //$this->_addAttachment($mailTemplate, $pdfGenerator->getPdf($postObject), 'giftcard.pdf');
            $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $storeId))
                ->sendTransactional(
                    Mage::getStoreConfig($template, $storeId),
                    'general',
                    $email,
                    null,
                    array('data' => $postObject)
                );
            $translate->setTranslateInline(true);
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Invalid recipient email address.');
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is in your below code

```
if ((($card->getMailDeliveryDate() == null) || ($curDate == $card->getMailDeliveryDate())) && $card->getCardType() != 'offline') {
  $this->_send($post, 'giftcards/email/email_template', $mail, $storeId);
  $card->setCardStatus(1)->save();
  $order->setGcSent(1)->save();
}
```

you are setting `setGcSent(1)` on $order instead of `$card` try changing that code  to

```
 $card->setCardStatus(1)
      ->setGcSent(1)
      ->save();
```